# Is the usual sobolov space H^2(R^3) just the Hilbertspace L^2(R^3)?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

It is usually said that for a free particle in $R^3$, the free particle Hamiltonian acts on a Hilbert space $L^2(R^3)$. My question is whether "the usual Sobolev space" $H^2(R^3)$ is just the Hilbert space $L^2(R^3)$? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

No, it the space of all functions in $L^2(R^3)$ which have first and second order partial derivatives (in the distributional sense) in $L^2(R^3)$

Comment: Thank you for your help! If I may, two follow up questions: (1) So $H^2(R^3)$ is a subset of $L^2(R^3)$ correct? (2) Then why do we say that operators in quantum mechanics act "on" $L^2(R^3)$ instead of "in" $L^2(R^3)$ ?

Comment: Yes, $H^2(R^3)$ is a subset of $L^2(R^3)$. As for your second question, I don't know what they mean. It depends on the context I guess.